# alternative to label.visible =true/false

Tags: asp.net

i feel like I'm doing something wrong for a long time already. I usually have some fields, for example: lets take upload control I select a file and then click upload button. So It should tell me whether there was "no file selected" or "uploaded successfully".
What I do is: I hide both labels and then I enable them in code behind depending on condition. If I am going to change file again, or I have more states, then my code become messy with a lot of label.visible=true statements. How do you handle this thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use one `Label` control, then set its `.Text` property in your code behind based on the message you want to pass to the client.

ASP:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMessage"></asp:Label>
```

C#:

```
lblMessage.Text = "Something happened that you should be aware of.";
```

Comment: +1 I would do this as well, only I would not use labels but literals

Comment: Both controls are valid in this situation.  I would use a `Literal` myself as well, though.

Comment: You might also want to add the EnableViewState="false" attribute.  That way, your error message will automatically clear itself on your next postback; you'll never have to write lblMessage.Text = string.Empty anywhere in your code-behind.  Of course, if you DO want the message to stay visible through multiple postbacks, don't do this.  :)  But I've found that in many cases, the error message is really meaningful only for the most recent postback operation.

Comment: And of course, you wouldn't want to hardcode user-visible messages in your code-behind - ideally they'd be in (localizable) resource files.  I'm sure Kyle knows this, but omitted it for the sake of brevity and readability.  ;)

Comment: +1 and +1 @mikemanne Good points, and you hit the nail on the head.  I wasn't trying to go into intricate detail, just providing enough information to answer the question.